# Find missing setting

Tags: sql-server-2012

I have two tables in my DB. Table A is informational data table and Table B is a setting table. How do I find Table A is missing one of the setting in Table B.

E.G.

```
Table A
username       setting
Mark           1
Mark           2
Martin         2
Jane           1

Table B
Possible_Setting
1             
2             
3

Result Table
username      missing_setting
Mark          3
Martin        1
Martin        3
Jane          2
Jane          3
```

Thanks for help!

Comment: See [this great explanation of joins](https://blog.codinghorror.com/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins/) - 4th example

Answer (score 0):

This may be inefficient if table sizes are significant, owing to the cross join but its the only answer I could come up with.

```
    SELECT a.username, b.Possible_Setting AS missing_setting 
FROM 
    (SELECT DISTINCT username FROM TableA a) a 
    CROSS JOIN TableB b 
WHERE 
    NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT * 
        FROM TableA real_a 
        WHERE   real_a.username = a.username 
            AND real_a.setting = b.Possible_Setting)
ORDER BY 1, 2
```

Setup code:

```
CREATE TABLE TableA (username varchar(20), setting tinyint)
CREATE TABLE TableB (Possible_Setting tinyint PRIMARY KEY)

INSERT TableA VALUES 
('Mark',          1),
('Mark',          2),
('Martin',        2),
('Jane',           1)

INSERT TableB VALUES 
(1),
(2),
(3)
```